# How Could ship combat work?

Tags: dnd-5e, optional-rules, vehicles

A friend and I are wanting to run a smaller D&D 5E campaign set on the high seas, however the naval combat rules seem a little sparse.

Most of the information I have found has been located on pages 117–119 of the DMG, however the information is sparse and vague at best. I also know about rules on page 225 for cannons and ballistics damage and range. (this modified would work well)

I was wondering if there are any table top game rules that highlight how to do ship vs ship combat that could be modified to include boarding and ship vs beast combat (monster hunter style)? I am also looking for a system that takes in to account facing position, can be run on a hex map, has a movement system that makes sense, and is mostly in keeping with 5Es simplicity.

Comment: Have you looked in the DMG?

Comment: Yes but as stated there is little too no information on this subject, and what there is doesn't have Ship vs Ship or Ship vs Beast rulings

Comment: Ok, now that you have that, what would turn this from an acceptable question into a great question is to remove questions that are answered in the DMG (ship HP, speed, etc), and ask a single, specific question that isn't. You'll get much better answers that way.

Comment: Your question as currently stated is "How does ship combat work?", the only answer to that is "As per the rules for vehicles in the DMG". You say these are inadequate; ask a question that shows us you know how they work as written and what the inadequacies are.

Comment: If you have access to previous editions (particularly OD&D or AD&D 1e) ... do you find those to be enough for your purposes or not?  If not, what's missing?  Porting those rules into 5e would probably be a separate question.

Comment: As it stands this question's kinda asking for "any naval rules you've ever heard of."  There are a lot. "Includes facing" is the only requirement you've stated, which is really quite too broad.